# How do I install arm64 development libraries on an amd64 device in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, arm64, cross-compilation

I'm trying to install development libraries for ARM64 so I can cross-compile `arm64` software from my `amd64` device, using Ubuntu 22.04. I've managed to install the `aarch64-linux-gnu` packages, but I can't figure out how to install the `arm64` versions of the various dependencies I need. **How can I install the `arm64` variants of development libraries on Ubuntu 22.04?**

Comment: I too am running into a similar issues particularly w.r.t the aarch64-linux-gnu-pkg-config and glib-2.0.